# How to add a counter in gcc asm?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly

In the linux kernel code, when a spinlock is locked, the spin_lock function will spinning. The code of spin_lock is below:

```
static __always_inline void __ticket_spin_lock(raw_spinlock_t *lock)
{
    int inc = 0x00010000;
    int tmp;

    asm volatile(LOCK_PREFIX "xaddl %0, %1\n"
             "movzwl %w0, %2\n\t"
             "shrl $16, %0\n\t"
             "1:\t"
             "cmpl %0, %2\n\t"
             "je 2f\n\t"
             "rep ; nop\n\t"
             "movzwl %1, %2\n\t"
             /* don't need lfence here, because loads are in-order */
             "jmp 1b\n"
             "2:"
             : "+r" (inc), "+m" (lock->slock), "=&r" (tmp)
             :
             : "memory", "cc");
}
```

My question is:

How can I add a time counter to monitor the spinning time of the lock?Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rdtsc time stamp counter to measure the interval ,you can view the below links http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch06.html

http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly/Examples